# The filename myfilename.csv is not readable mistery bug in Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader

Tags: php, csv

I get this error message for some reason. The weird thing that my code works in the last few days, now I'm getting this: "**The filename /home/netlogiq/public_html/CUSTOM/importer/upload_csv/KC_redirects.csv is not readable**  ". In the forums, people are talk about that there is a problem with the path or permission, so I gave the persion 777 and I gave it the ultimate server path(see the code). This is my code

```
...
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    if(!chmod("upload_csv/".$fileName,0777))
    {
        echo "Unable to chmod $direcotry";
    }
    require_once('excel/reader.php');

    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

    $data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $file_path = "/home/netlogiq/public_html/CUSTOM/importer/upload_csv/".$fileName;
    $data->read($file_path);
    ....
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Have you checked if the file is locked by another program/process?

Comment: certainly, it is not used by another program or process.

Comment: Actually, I'm out of idea :(